# deploy jar file with external libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, classpath, executable-jar

I am finishing a project that I have to deploy as a jar file, in eclipse it works fine, my project depends on two libraries which also both depends on dll files. I have added the path to these dlls to the native library location of each one of the external jars. Then I export project as a jar file using the eclipse runnable jar file export wizard I get the jar file in the specified location, it runs but when I click on a button that calls one of the libraries I get  I get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path on the console.

**Edit** : When I copy the dlls in  [...]/jre7/bin/ folder my application works, but I want that my application runs without having to do this manipulation.

Regards.

Comment: Run your jar file with console. Using following command: `java -jar app.jar`

Comment: Yes I did and I get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path, I added the path to the dlls (which are on my desktop). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So the problem is your path for the file. You must read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944610/how-do-i-access-a-config-file-inside-the-jar

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, I solved a part of the problem thank you, I have edited my post.

Comment: you can mark my comment as helpful

Comment: Sorry I can't see how I can do that, there is just the comment.

Comment: Move your cursor before the comment you will find the arrow upward click on it.

Comment: I see the comments in little format, there are no arrows, I am sorry, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Run like this:  java -Djava.library.path=/path_to_dll -jar app.jar

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it did work but the problem is that I want the users to start the app normally without having to use a terminal. That means that the path should be added to the application before exporting to .jar, which I am unable to do. I found another solution to put the dlls inside  [...]/jre7/bin/ but that also needs manipulations from the end users.