# How to set path of a config.ini file in a Runnable Jar?

Tags: java, jar, yajsw

i'm doing a program in java, that  will be exported in a runnable JAR and executed in windows as service using YAJSW, i have to read a `config.ini` file that have important params for the execution, but i'm setting a fixed path:

```
Path configFile = Paths.get("D:\\Folder\\config.ini");
```

The problem is that i don't know the path where it will be executed on final user pc.
i tried this:

```
Path txtParametro = Paths.get("\\config.ini");
```

because the .ini file will be in the same folder of .jar, but didn't work.

Someone has any idea of how i can handle this?

I thought of environment variables ... but would have to manually do it, is not an option.

Comment: you need to find out the directory of the jar file :) probably from system property `java.class.path`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the file to be created in a specific location so that the program will always know where it will be:

```
File file = new File("D:\\Folder\\config.ini");
if (!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Regards,
    Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If the file is part of the JAR then you could load it like this:

Class.getResourceAsStream("config.ini");

As described here:

[How do I access a config file inside the jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944610/how-do-i-access-a-config-file-inside-the-jar)

If not in A JAR please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, that way:

assuming that `config.ini` is in the same folder of .jar

```
File pathJAR = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
```

it returns me the path of running jar, `"D:\Folder\name.jar"`, then i replaces "name.jar" by "config.ini".

not so beatiful, but works.